# Is there some fast and efficient way for solving $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices

Let $b$ be a given constant scalar between 0 and 1, and $A$ a given $N \times N$ transitional probability matrix (i.e., each row sum of $A$ is 1, and $0\le {A}_{(i,j)} \le 1$). 
Let $A\circ A$ denote the element-wise product of $A$ and itself (i,e,. $(A\circ A)_{(i,j)}={(A_{(i,j)})}^2$. Here, $A_{(i,j)}$ represents the $(i,j)$-th entry of the matrix $A$.

Is there a fast efficient method for computing the following $x$:

$$x = {\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \Big(b^k \cdot \Big(A^k \circ A^k \Big)\Big)\bigg)}^{-1} \cdot \vec1$$

where $\vec1$ is a $N \times 1$ vector with the elements of all 1s.

======

PS:

I guess there should be some fast ways for computing the above expression because if $\Big((A^k) \circ(A^k)\Big)$ is replaced by $A^k$ in the above expression, then the expression

$${\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \Big(b^k \cdot A^k \Big)\bigg)}^{-1} \cdot \vec1$$

can be computed as follows:

$$= (I-bA)\cdot \vec1 = (1- b) \cdot \vec1 .$$

Any kind suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: I suggest that you change $\otimes$ to $\circ$ in your post, which is one of the standard notations for the Hadamard product that you are using. Symbol $\otimes$ usually denotes tensor or Kronecker product which is something else and will only confuse people.

Comment: @Conifold, Good suggestion. Done.